# Kendo grid is not working at web side(front side) of nopcommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, nopcommerce

my kendo ui grid is not working at web side(front side) of the nop commerce but if

i have displayed kendo grid at back end side but and write same code at front side but its not display me kendo grid.i have write same code at admin side its working properly whats the problem. is any dll or other thing should i have to add plz tell me.

Comment: what error you get... plese share you code.... so i can evaluate it...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by myself its not working on fornt side of nop commerce because kendo has its own css & jquery and when we are try to put at front side of the nop commerce its not probably working as it so i prefer to not to use kendo ui at front end side of nop commerce.